# What's the difference between verbs forward and redirect?

Tags: word-meaning, difference

According to [dictionary.cambridge.org/forward](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/forward), the verb ***forward*** means

> to send a letter, etc., especially from someone's old address to their
> new address, or to send a letter, email, etc. that you have received
> to someone else

And according to [dictionary.cambridge.org/redirect](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/redirect), the verb ***redirect*** means

> to change the direction of something, especially to send a letter to a
> new address

What's the difference? When to use *forward* and when *redirect*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the UK these terms could be used interchangeably, but often I would interpret the meanings like this:

> **Forward:**
> Person A sends something to person B, who receives it, but it needs to go to person C,
> so person B **forwards** it to person C.
>
> If I move into a house, and a letter comes addressed to a previous occupant,
> and I know that person's new address (their '**forwarding address**'),
> I can **forward** that letter to them, by taking a pen, crossing out
> the address on the front, writing the new address next to it, and
> posting it (without paying for a new stamp). Also, for example, if I
> accidentally damage someone's property, I might say 'Get it repaired
> and **forward** the bill to me'. Perhaps I am involved in some legal matter, and I get a document which I can't deal with, so I **forward** it to my lawyer.

> **Redirect:**
> Person A sends something to person B, but person B has changed
> address. The mail service can change the address on the item and
> deliver it there.
>
> If I leave an address, I can pay a fee to Royal Mail for
> '**redirection** service' for a period, usually six months or a year.
> Using a form, I tell them the old and new addresses, pay the fee, and staff at the area delivery
> office serving the old address will (hopefully) grab any letters
> arriving with my name at the old address, and change the delivery
> address (using labels they printed) and put them back in the postal
> system (**redirect** them). These never get to the old address.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either; they are just different ways of saying the same thing. *Forward* has the sense 'send (something you have received) onwards', and *redirect* that of 'write a different address on'.

Comment: Thanks! My little off-topic: you wrote _"either"_ in the meaning of _"any of two"_. Can the word _"either"_ be also using if there are more than two items?

Comment: Some dictionaries say 'a choice between two', some say 'two or more'. It's usually _either of two, any of several_.